# Represent matrix in einstein notation with kronecker deltas

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

Define an $(n \times m)$ matrix $E_{(i,j)}$ as the matrix which has one element, element $(i,j)$, that is equal to $1$ and the rest equal to $0$. Assume $A$ is an arbitrary matrix of shape $(m \times k)$. I am trying to write the following sum in einstein notation:

$$B = \sum_{i, j}E_{(i, j)} A$$

However I am getting confused. For arbitrary indices $(k, l, m, n)$ I know that element $(m, n)$ of $E_{(k, l)}$ equals $1$ if and only if $k=m$ and $l=n$.

From this I would assume that multiplication by $E_{(k, l)}$ would look something like $\delta^k_m\delta^l_n$ in Einstein notation, where $\delta$ is the kronecker delta.

However, in matrix form the kronecker delta is the identity matrix and $E_{(k, l)}$ is not a product of identity matrices. I am very confused, please could someone provide some intuition on how to represent $E_{(k, l)}$ in relation to einstein notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You situation is similar to that of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/436667/81360). Let $C$ denote the matrix whose entries are all equal to $1$. We can then write your sum as
$$
\left[\sum_{i,j} E_{(i,j)} A\right]_{p,q} = \delta_{pi}\delta_{ij}C_{ij} A_{jq}.
$$
Alternatively, you might prefer to use $1_{ij}$ to denote the entries of the matrix whose entries are all equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess my confusion also stems from the fact that $m\neq n \neq k$ so if I were to try and express my equation in matrix form I could end up with $\delta_{i, j} $ corresponding to a non-square matrix and thus might not be the identity. Can ricci calculus notation be used to matrix algebra involving non-square matrices? Looking at the definition of a tensor I'm thinking not...

Comment: @JDoe2 It can! For example, if $A$ has size $m \times p$ and $B$ has size $p \times n$, then 
$$
[AB]_{ij} = A_{ik}B_{kj}
$$
This works in the above case because the number of columns in $A$ (corresponding to the first $k$ index) matches the number of rows in $B$ (corresponding to the second). We just need to be careful about which indices are repeated

Comment: I guess my confusion is if I have the below matrix equation:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}B$$

where $A$ is $(2 \times 4)$ in size and $B$ is $(4 \times 4)$ in size, then if I were to write it as a tensor it would look like:

$$A^i_k=\delta^i_jB^j_k$$ 

where $\delta^i_j$ does satisfy the definition of the kronecker delta (as it is $1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise) but doesnt correspond to the identity matrix. 

By the above, it must be true that either $\delta^i_j$ doesn't always correspond to the identity or tensors must be square. Which is true?

Comment: $\delta^i_j$ does not always correspond to the identity. It only corresponds to the identity if the (implicit) bounds on $i$ and $j$ are the same.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining this to me! It is very appreciated! I don't suppose you know any good references with good discussion of these sort of nuances in ricci calculus notation?

Comment: I don't, sorry. That might be a good question to ask with the [tag:reference-request] tag

Comment: Okay, no worries! Thanks again!